# Verificação no banco com ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Nunca trabalhei com ajax mas preciso em um formulário fazer uma pesquisa no `MySQL` pra verificar se o login que o usuário tá digitando já existe.

No campo input eu coloquei um `onBlur` pra quando o cara pular de campo o sistema faça a verificação se existe aquele login.

Tipo pequei até um modelo na net mas está incompleto o que faço depois?

```
function TestaLogin(){

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'VerificaDados.php', 
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:'json',                
                data: {"Cpf" : $("#cpf").val()}, 
                success: function(data) { 

                /*** Não faz nada pois está ok*/
            } 


        }); 

}
```

O que eu faço agora do lado do PHP? Como pego essa variável? Pesquisar no banco eu sei, montar o `SQL` tranquilo, mas e como eu retorno uma resposta pra
app e se caso não for positivo tipo existir aquele login o que eu coloco do lado do `javascript` pra sinalizar que existe?

Comment: Faça como faz normalmente, `$_POST['cpf']`, para retornar basta um `echo 'sucesso ou falha';` ou pode mandar um json.

Comment: adicione um error: function(data) { alert(data); }. Você tem que verificar duas coisas: Se o nome e caminho do arquivo VerificaDados.php esta certo e se ele esta de fato retornando um JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parte do PHP

caso user marcara usei um array para remover os caracteres indesejados.

```
$retira = array('.','-','(',')',' ','/','_');
$cpf = isset($_REQUEST["cpf"]) ? trim(str_replace($retira, '', $_REQUEST["cpf"])) : null;

//consulta no banco de dados
$result = $_container['cadastroFornecedores']->searchCpf($cpf);

//se retornar é porque existe já e voce retorna ele próprio
//caso contrário retorna vazio, ou o que for necessário
if(sizeof($result) == 0){
   echo $cpf;
}else{
   echo '';
}
```

fiz algo do genero em javascript veja se lhe ajuda.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#usuario_cpf').blur( function(){

        if ($('#usuario_cpf').val() != ''){

            var dados = $('#usuario_cpf').val();

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'search-cpf.php',
                data: {
                    cpf: dados
                },
                beforeSend: function(){
                     $('.load-cpf').css({
                         display: 'block'
                     });
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $('#usuario_cpf').val(data);
                    if($('#usuario_cpf').val() == ''){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#usuario_cpf').val(data);
                            $('.load-cpf').css({
                                display: 'none'
                            });
                            $('.error-cpf').css('display', 'block').fadeOut(2000);
                        }, 500)
                    }else{
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#usuario_cpf').val(data);

                            $('.load-cpf').css({
                                display: 'none'
                            });
                        }, 500);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Pow deu certinho essa segunda opção! Não tenho como agradecer... Muito obrigado! A primeira acredito que esteja certa tbm valew aos dois! :D

Answer (score 1):

Na parte do código "success: function(data){}", na variável `data` você terá o que você recebeu de resposta, ou seja, resposta da URL chamada.

Em uma opinião pessoal, você pode fazer um novo arquivo .php que verifica se o login existe, recebendo o login que será verificado por POST e depois escreva se já existe ou não. Este conteúdo que você colocar no novo arquivo .php é o você receberá na variável `data`. Depois daí você pode fazer um campo na sua página que receba este conteúdo, exemplo:

> arquivo .php

```
<?php
     $login = $_POST['loginParaVerificar'];
     $loginJaExiste = verificaLoginExistente($login);
     if($loginJaExiste){
          echo "Este login já existe no sistema";
     }else{
          echo "Este login NÃO existe no sistema";
     }
?>
```

> no AJAX

```
success: fucntion(data){
        $('#divResposta').html(data);
        alert('AJAX retornado com sucesso!');
    }
```

*** Nota-se, o novo arquivo .php neste caso pode conter conteúdo HTML e não só a mensagem, onde a variável data será composta pelo todo. Espero ter ajudado.